# Caffe - Create deploy.prototxt from train_val.prototxt

Tags: matlab, input, hdf5, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have finetuned the imagenet pretrained model on my dataset, following are the relevant changes made in train_val.prototxt (Also I have not done oversampling, just the centre crop while preparing hdf5)

```
name: "MyCaffeNet"
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "X"  
  top: "Meta" 
  top: "Labels"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/hdf5_train.txt"
    batch_size: 50
  }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "X"    
  top: "Meta" 
  top: "Labels"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/hdf5_test.txt"
    batch_size: 50
 }
  include { phase: TEST }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "X"
```

The rest is same till

```
layer {
  name: "concat"
  bottom: "fc7"
  bottom: "Meta"
  top: "combined"
  type: "Concat"
  concat_param {
    concat_dim: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "my-fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "combined"
  top: "my-fc8"
  # lr_mult is set to higher than for other layers, because this layer is starting from random while the others are already trained
  param {
    lr_mult: 10
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 20
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4098
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
 }
}
layer {
  name: "my-fc9"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "my-fc8"
  top: "my-fc9"
  # lr_mult is set to higher than for other layers, because this layer is starting from random while the others are already trained
  param {
    lr_mult: 10
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 20
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "my-fc9"
  bottom: "Labels"
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "my-fc9"
  bottom: "Labels"
  top: "loss"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

The question is I don't get how to modify my deploy.prototxt and my feature extraction code (which is given below) to test this model, now with the extra meta info as input features

```
for i=1:n
    im = fgetl(file_list);
    im = imread(im);
    input_data = {prepare_image(im)};
    scores = caffe('forward', input_data);
    scores_original=scores;
    scores = scores{1};
    scores = squeeze(scores);
end
```

Here prepare_image does rgb to bgr, permute and centre crop stuff, basically preprocessing.

So, it boils down to how should I modify 'caffe('forward', input_data)'; and make a deploy.prototxt so that while testing caffe is also fed the Meta (n*2) features. Thanks for your patience and help!

I think deploy.prototxt beginning should be something like

```
name: "MyCaffeNet"
input: "X"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 227
input_dim: 227
input: "Meta"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 2 # two additional 'features' per image
```

Comment: And if someone can also verify the correctness of the train_val, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Basically, if I could pass 2 input blobs to the caffe forward function like,
caffe('forward',image_data,meta_data) my problem would be solved.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quick sure your question about. But if you want to "Convert train_val.prototxt to deploy.prototxt" you can click [HERE](https://sites.duke.edu/rachelmemo/2015/05/05/convert-train_val-prototxt-to-deploy-prototxt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable input_data can be a vector of 4-D blobs. The function prepare_data gives a 4D blob of image data similarly one can reshape adequately meta or any other kind of input to a 4D blob and then pass it to the forward function.

`input_data = {prepare_data(im),prepare_meta()};`

`scores = caffe('forward', input_data')`;